# How to enable Gradient Buttons (plus and minus) on macOS SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

Is there a way to enable Gradient Buttons [ + | – ] with SwiftUI? Can't find any useful information about this topic.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/menus-and-actions/buttons#gradient-buttons/

[image]

---

### Update

I made a few cosmetic changes to @workingdogsupportUkraine answer. Now Gradient Buttons looks similar as in the Settings app on macOS 13. Please feel free to suggest any enhancements

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    @State private var selection: Int?

    struct GradientButton: View {
        var glyph: String
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Image(systemName: glyph)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                Color.clear
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                List(selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 5) { Text("Item \($0)") }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 24)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom, content: {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        Divider()
                        HStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                GradientButton(glyph: "plus")
                            }
                            Divider().frame(height: 16)
                            Button(action: {}) {
                                GradientButton(glyph: "minus")
                            }
                            .disabled(selection == nil ? true : false)
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                    }
                    .background(Rectangle().opacity(0.04))
                })
            }
        }
        .formStyle(.grouped)
    }
}
```

Comment: Context is not clear, provide minimal reproducible example with details on what's wrong and what's expected instead.

Comment: as far as I know, you have to construct the type you want with the
 available SwiftUI views, like `Button`, `Picker` etc... to achieve the
 behaviour you desire, such as, push buttons, toggles, or pop-up buttons.
 Show us the code you have already tried. Use the SF symbols, "plus" and "minus" in the `Image()`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine this is exactly what I wanted to know: should I recreate this controllers or there is default appearance can be enabled. I will post my solution here soon. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something simple like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5) { Text("item \($0)") }
            HStack {
                Button(action: {print("plus")}) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.small)
                }
                Divider()
                Button(action: {print("minus")}) {
                    Image(systemName: "minus").imageScale(.small)
                }
            }.buttonStyle(.borderless)
             .frame(width: 66, height: 33)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed your answer a bit to conform to the macOS 13 style 